# Display image and file in a folder

Tags: php, image, directory

I would like to display the content of a folder, with an image and the file name next to it.
I have tried to get the file name via `scandir`, but it would not change line, just out in 1 long line.

What i really want is something like this:
`[Image here]    [name here]`

code:

```
$directory = '../../Images'; 
$files = scandir($directory);
print_r($files);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried and what didn't work? This isn't much to work with at the moment.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code, don't add it as a comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that every file in the directory is an image:

```
<?php

$directory = './images';

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $fn)
{
    if (!$fn->isDir() && !$fn->isDot())
    {
        printf("<p><img src=\"./images/%1\$s\" /> %1\$s</p>\n", $fn->getFilename());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i did, i changes it to, ../../Images :)

Comment: What was the result of this then? DirectoryIterator will throw an error if it can't read the directory.

Comment: Well, it shows the file names, but the images are just the small failed ones,the small squares..
You can see it here http://japseyz.dk/JapSeyz/Admin/Packages/Imagelist

Comment: Ok so the listing is working but your images aren't showing. The image directory must be in a publicly accessible folder and your image path should point to that folder. If "../../Images" is moving out of your web root then those images can never be served by your web server.

Comment: it is publicy accessible and it is not moving out of the web server, so i don't know what is wrong :/ you can try the link from my previous comment, and see it is publicly visible

Comment: The URL its trying to load is this: http://japseyz.dk/JapSeyz/Admin/Packages/images/AvatarOnline.jpg. And the image doesn't live there. Fix the image path to exactly where it resides.

Comment: No, the image is at JapSeyz.dk/JapSeyz/Images/AvatarOnline.jpg thats why the ../../Images is there

Comment: Replace `<img src=\"./images/%1\$s\" />` with `<img src=\"http://JapSeyz.dk/JapSeyz/Images/%1\$s\" />` then. The problem you have with my solution is probably something similar, you either didn't set $root or $directory to the right value or there's some typo somewhere.

Comment: Thanks this works.
But i would really love to get something like this going.
$files = scandir($directory);

print_r($files);

So i can style it in a table

Comment: How you pull the data and how you display the data are two different things, you can format your data whether the data was sourced from `scandir`, `DirectoryIterator` or `pull_data_from_unicorns()`.

Answer (score 0):

Table would work. But you have to surround it with `<html> <body>` and so on if you want it to render properly.

```
$root = 'http://example.com/images/';
$files = scandir( $directory );
echo '<table>';
foreach( $files as $file )
{
    if(is_file($file))
    {
        echo '<tr><td><img src="' . $root . $file . '" /></td><td>' . $file . '</td></tr>';
    }
}
echo '</table>
```